# Atmosphere: How to subscribe to an API call?

Tags: angularjs, rest, websocket, atmosphere

I am using [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere) plugin.The goal is to notify client to reload data when somebody calls update API.

1)I am not sure if my approach is correct. Is it fine to have atmosphere part in separate class?
2)Secondly my client side code is in angularjs and I couldn't find any angularjs example to subscribe to update event and how to handle trigger event when a notification arrives?
Here is my sever side code:

```
@Path("/students")

public class StudentResource {
   @PUT
   @Path("/{studentID}/update")
   public void updateStudentInfo(@PathParam("studentID")                                
                                 studnetId,StudentInfo info) {
    //studentInfo will get updated
   }
}
```

Then for atmosphere part in server side:

```
@Path("/students/{studentID}/update")
public class JerseyPubSub {

    private
    @PathParam("studentID")
    Broadcaster id

    @GET
    public SuspendResponse<String> subscribe() {
            return new SuspendResponse.SuspendResponseBuilder<String>()
            .broadcaster(id)
            .outputComments(true)
            .addListener(new EventsLogger())
            .build();
    }

    @POST
    @Broadcast
    @Produces("text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1")
    public Broadcastable publish(@FormParam("message") String message) {
           return new Broadcastable(message, "", id);
    }
}
```